# I'm trying to make a mod menu in a website with bookmarklet, but for some reason it doesn't show up

Tags: javascript

So I've been trying to make a mod menu to hack iReady as a bookmarklet, I'm a beginner to HTML, so I've started by making one button show up. It shows up on the main pages, but in the lessons, the button disappears. When I exit the lesson, the button shows back up. My code:

```
let c = document.createElement('div');
  c.innerHTML = `<button onclick="test()">test</button>`;
  document.body.appendChild(c);
```

*yes I just made a button, I'm trying to get the button to show up first.*

Comment: I have no idea how iReady works as a website, but it sounds like the lesson is either overlaying the main page, or is replacing it. If it is overlaying it, add CSS to your `div` to set it to `position: absolute; z-index: 100000;` or something equally high and see if that works. If you want more help, you'll need to provide sample HTML and CSS of the iReady page when the lesson is displayed.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah thanks, that worked :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to put the code in either an onload function or in script tags at the end of the body to run after the page has loaded?

In the head:

```
<head>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            let div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
            let button = document.createElement('button');
            button.setAttribute('onclick', 'test()')
            button.innerHTML = 'test';
            div.append(button);
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Or in the body:

```
<body>
    <!-- some other html -->
    <script>
        let div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        let button = document.createElement('button');
        button.setAttribute('onclick', 'test()')
        button.innerHTML = 'test';
        div.append(button);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a thing like a mod menu and it makes buttons like you are trying to do and its a bookmarklet!

here it is:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bjavascript%3A (function main() %7B%0A  %2F* I add random characters at the end of the ID so that it does not clash with any other ID's on the page *%2F%0A%0A  const ID %3D%0A    '--picture-in-picture-toolbar-8743fsfjkl9274g9832fkjdslfjksl7498247389'%3B %2F* Helper functions *%2F%0A  const get %3D (selector%2C el %3D document) %3D> el.querySelector(selector)%3B%0A  const getAll %3D (selector%2C el %3D document) %3D>%0A    Array.from(el.querySelectorAll(selector))%3B%0A  %2F* Remove our toolbar if it exists *%2F let _toolbar %3D get(%60%23%24%7BID%7D%60)%3B%0A  if (_toolbar) %7B%0A    _toolbar.parent.removeChild(_toolbar)%3B%0A  %7D%0A  %2F* create the toolbar *%2F const toolbar %3D document.createElement(%0A    'div'%0A  )%3B %2F* Set the toolbar's ID%2C so we can remove it later *%2F%0A  toolbar.id %3D ID%3B %2F* Use shadow-dom as outlined here%3A https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fweb%2Ffundamentals%2Fweb-components%2Fshadowdom *%2F%0A  %2F* Inside shadow dom we don't have to worry about conflicting styles. *%2F const shadowroot %3D toolbar.attachShadow(%0A    %7B mode%3A 'open' %7D%0A  )%3B%0A  shadowroot.innerHTML %3D %60<style>%23container %7B  z-index%3A 9999%3B  border%3A 1px solid %23000%3B  border-radius%3A 3px%3B  padding%3A 0.7em%3B  position%3A fixed%3B  top%3A 0.5em%3B  right%3A 0.5em%3B  background-color%3A rgba(0%2C0%2C0%2C0.7)%3B  font-family%3A -apple-system%2CBlinkMacSystemFont%2C"Segoe UI"%2CRoboto%2C"Helvetica Neue"%2CArial%2C"Noto Sans"%2Csans-serif%2C"Apple Color Emoji"%2C"Segoe UI Emoji"%2C"Segoe UI Symbol"%2C"Noto Color Emoji"%3B%7Dbutton %7B  padding%3A 0.5em 0.7em%3B  border-radius%3A 3px%3B  box-shadow%3A none%3B  border%3A 2px solid %23fff%3B  background-color%3A transparent%3B  color%3A %23fff%3B  cursor%3A pointer%3B%7Dbutton%3Ahover %7B  background-color%3A white%3B  color%3A black%3B%7D<%2Fstyle><div id%3D"container">  <button aria-label%3D"click to alert" id%3D"alert">    Click to Alert  <%2Fbutton> %0A  <button onclick%3D"myFunction()">Click me<%2Fbutton>%0A  <button onclick%3D"myFunction()">Click me<%2Fbutton>%0A  <button onclick%3D"myFunction()">Click me<%2Fbutton>%0A  %0A  <button aria-label%3D"close" id%3D"close">    x  <%2Fbutton><%2Fdiv>    %60%3B%0A  %0A  %0A  get('%23close'%2C shadowroot).addEventListener('click'%2C () %3D> %7B%0A    const toolbar %3D get(%60%23%24%7BID%7D%60)%3B%0A    if (toolbar) %7B%0A      toolbar.parentNode.removeChild(toolbar)%3B%0A    %7D%0A  %7D)%3B%0A  const alertEl %3D get('%23alert'%2C shadowroot)%3B%0A  alertEl.addEventListener('click'%2C e %3D> %7B%0A    alert('You clicked to alert')%3B%0A  %7D)%3B%0A  document.body.appendChild(toolbar)%3B%0A%7D)()%3B%7D)()%3B
```